# How can i use the libraries after importing dependencies using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am facing issues in actually using the libraries contained within the dependancies. I followed the procedure up to the letter but yet xcode gives me errors when i try to import the kit i need to use. Heres what i have done:

1. create pod file at the project directory
2. install the pod file with dependancies
3. open .xcworkspace file created
4. create a bridging header in objective c
5. enter path of the bridging header to the build settings

After doing all of this, when i write the import statement (eg. import IMFData) xcode shows that it doesnt exist/ cant be found.

Could somebody shed some light on the what i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `use_frameworks!` to your pod file and then run `pod install` again. You won't need to use a bridging header then and will be able todo `import IMFData` alternatively if you aren't using Frameworks when you use the bridging header you don't need to use the `import IMFData` just access the classes within your swift class.

Comment: I included the use frameworks statement but i seem to be getting another error after doing so:

[!] The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: <path of my file>

This is happening in the terminal btw

Comment: @Jobs have a look at this discussion https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3267